# How to know if a deadbeat parent is a US citizen?

Tags: passports, us-citizens, applications

My girlfriend is applying for a US passport. The application asks for, among other things, information about the parents. About whether or not they're US citizens.

Most of the requested information is on the birth certificate but US citizenship of the parents is not. And, in the case of the father, it's not like he can be asked, since he was a dead beat father. Whether or not he is even still alive is unknown.

So how should this question be answered?

Comment: Put 'unknown', it works. I know a person who's father disappeared before birth, no data known, and it worked fine.

Comment: @Aganju why not post this as an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most likely reason the passport office would care about your girlfriend's parents' nationality would be in case it is necessary to determine whether she is a US citizen.  I assume that she is a US citizen independent of her father's nationality (which would only be relevant if she had been born outside the US, and, depending on when she was born, on her mother's circumstances).  If that assumption is correct, then she should put "unknown" for her father's citizenship.